# Assistance with a dynamically generated field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have another dynamic question for you.  I have three input fields that I need to enter values for.  These `"dijit_form_DateTextBox_36"` are created dynamically (the 36 is variable).  There is a value earlier in the code that is unique and can be searched for.  I know I need to use something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'QA GM 04012014 1424 Item Name')]/parent::...somepath.sendKeys("...");
```

But I am still too new to this stuff to be able to figure it out.  And if someone can assist me with what I need to put, as well as how they figured it out, I would greatly appreciate it.  I'd really love to solve these on my own!  Code is below.  Bolded portion is the static text that can be searched.  Bolded and italicized lines are the three controls that need to be modified.  NOTE:  The `id="shipDate0_0"` is also dynamic, it can be `shipDate0_0`, `shipDate1_0`, etc.  So can't key on that.

```
    <tr class="tableControlHeader twTableHeaderTR"></tr>
    <tr class="tableControlDataRow evenRow twTableTR">
    <td class="twTableTD details" align="center" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="twTableTD details" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <p>
            <b>

                QA GM 04012014 1424 Item Name

            </b>
        </p>
        <br></br>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </td>
    <td class="twTableTD" align="center" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="twTableTD" align="center"></td>
    <td class="twTableTD" align="center"></td>
    <td id="shipDate0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center">
        <div style="padding-right: 20px;">
            <div id="dateWrap-projectedFirstShipDate_0_0" class="inputText_Full twControl twDateSelector" ;="" onblur="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)" initialvalue="" value="" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#projectedFirstShipDate" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <div id="projectedFirstShipDate_0_0" lang="" dojoattachpoint="pickerDiv" widgetid="projectedFirstShipDate_0_0" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#projectedFirstShipDate">
                    <span dojoattachpoint="leftPicker">
                        <div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_36" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dateSelectionSin…tBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick" role="combobox" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_36">
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" popupactive="true"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
                                <input id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_36" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" aria-valuenow="null" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" value="" style="" delocalized="null" aria-disabled="false"></input>
                                <input type="hidden" value=""></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span dojoattachpoint="rightPicker"></span>
                    <span style="position: absolute;" dojoattachpoint="calImage"></span>
                    <input id="projectedFirstShipDate_0_0" type="text" isdatefield="true" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#projectedFirstShipDate" style="display:none" dojoattachpoint="hiddenInput" delocalized="null"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td id="InDate0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" ;="" onclick="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)">
        <div style="padding-right: 20px;">
            <div id="dateWrap-inDate_0_0" class="inputText_Full twControl twDateSelector" ;="" onblur="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)" initialvalue="" value="" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#inDate" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <div id="inDate_0_0" lang="" dojoattachpoint="pickerDiv" widgetid="inDate_0_0" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#inDate">
                    <span dojoattachpoint="leftPicker">
                        <div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_35" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dateSelectionSin…tBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick" role="combobox" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_35">
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" popupactive="true"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
                                <input id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_35" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" aria-valuenow="null" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" value="" style="" delocalized="null" aria-disabled="false"></input>
                                <input type="hidden" value=""></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span dojoattachpoint="rightPicker"></span>
                    <span style="position: absolute;" dojoattachpoint="calImage"></span>
                    <input id="inDate_0_0" type="text" isdatefield="true" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#inDate" style="display:none" dojoattachpoint="hiddenInput" delocalized="null"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td id="OutDate0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" onclick="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)">
        <div style="padding-right: 20px;">
            <div id="dateWrap-outDate_0_0" class="inputText_Full twControl twDateSelector" ;="" onblur="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)" initialvalue="" value="" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#outDate" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <div id="outDate_0_0" lang="" dojoattachpoint="pickerDiv" widgetid="outDate_0_0" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#outDate">
                    <span dojoattachpoint="leftPicker">
                        <div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_34" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dateSelectionSin…tBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick" role="combobox" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_34">
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" popupactive="true"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"></div>
                            <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
                                <input id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_34" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" aria-valuenow="null" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" value="" style="" delocalized="null" aria-disabled="false"></input>
                                <input type="hidden" value=""></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span dojoattachpoint="rightPicker"></span>
                    <span style="position: absolute;" dojoattachpoint="calImage"></span>
                    <input id="outDate_0_0" type="text" isdatefield="true" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#outDate" style="display:none" dojoattachpoint="hiddenInput" delocalized="null"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td id="BuyQuantity0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" onblur="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)" name="BuyQuantity0"></td>
    <td id="TotalCost0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" name="TotalCost0"></td>
    <td id="NumberOfWarehouses0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" onblur="updateAvgPerWeek(0,0)" td=""></td>
    <!--

    # of Warehouses

    -->
    <td id="AveragePerWarehouse0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" name="AvgPerWhouseWeek0"></td>
    <!--

    Cost per Warehouse

    -->`enter code here`
    <td id="ProjectedSellPrice0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center" td=""></td>
    <!--

     Projected Sell Price 

    -->
    <td id="PercentOfTotal0_0" class="twTableTD" align="center"></td>
    <td class="twTableTD" align="center" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm able to work my way up to the parent row with ...  //b[contains(., 'QA GM 04012014 1424 Item Name')]/parent::p/parent::td/parent::tr ... Now to figure out how to drill down to the item I want.  Having difficulty with that.

Comment: Whoa, you might want to trim your code snippet down to just the element in question, and some surrounding elements

Comment: Hopefully I've trimmed it to only the parts right around the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best xpath I am able to come up with is this:

```
//td[normalize-space()='QA GM 04012014 1424 Item Name']/following-sibling::td[contains(@id, 'shipDate')]//input[contains(@class,'dijitInputInner')]
```

Let me explain:

This part finds the td element with the text you're looking for, the normalize-space() call is just like text(), but trims any whitespace before/after the text & I've found it to be invaluable since discovering it a short time ago. text() will return whitespace and is often difficult to match

> `//td[normalize-space()='QA GM 04012014 1424 Item Name']`

This next part finds ALL td's after the previous element. From the code snippet provided this will find ALL 13 td's that follow

> `/following-sibling::td`

Narrow down that set of 13 by finding only the td containing the ID you're interested in, this is better than using a hardcoded number like `/following-sibling::td[2]` to find the second td

> `/following-sibling::td[contains(@id, 'shipDate')]`

Then find the input field that you're interested in, there are number of ways you could do this, choose whichever you prefer

```
//input[contains(@class,'dijitInputInner')]
//input[contains(@id,'dijit_form_DateTextBox')]
```

I hope that's clear enough & works well for you, please let me know if not

Comment: That worked!  It was a lot cleaner than what I came up with.  I came up with "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[contains(., '" + prop.getProperty("item.text") + " Item Name" + "')]/parent::p/parent::td/parent::tr/td[6]/div/div/div/span/div/div[3]/input")).clear();".  Thanks!